# Logstash+ES+Kibana setup?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have `logstash-1.4.1`, `elasticsearch-1.1.1` and `kibana-3.1.0` downloaded on my machine. Presently I do the following steps to run the three and view my logs:

1. run `./bin/elasticsearch` to start elastic search.
2. run `bin/logstash -f logstash-simple.conf` to start logstash. So till here my logs are stored in ES.
3. To view my logs, I go to kibana-3.1.0 folder and open the `index.html` file inside it and I select a dashboard and my logs appear and am able to analyze them.

So presently index.html is run and a local file url is displayed in the browser with directory structure of the index file: `file:///path/to/file/kibana-3.1.0/index.html#/dashboard/file/default.json`

I want to view my logs via a proper url (which I can also give it to my client to run). If I try `http://this.is.my.ip:9200//_search?pretty=true`, I get to see logs in plain text format (the way it is stored in ES).

How should I able too view my logs with a URL (not the index.html). I want to give it to the client so that he can view logs through it's machine.

If I try `http://this.is.my.ip:9200/kibana`, I get `No handler found for uri [/kibana] and method [GET]`.

I am new to this. I guess am missing something. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an web server, for example apache run at port 80,  and put kibana folder into apache htdocs folder. So, you will have the URL: `http:/this.is.my.ip/kibana-3.1.0/index.html`

Then you want view your logs via the link above. Also, you can give this url to your client.

Comment: So for my local machine I can just open index.html placed on my machine and to view logs from a separate machine I need a web server???

Comment: Yes! Actually Kibana is a static html+js site. So, you need to provide a web server for client to get this file and connect to your ES.

Comment: Ok! So presently I hava jboss AS on my machine. Do I need Apache webserver specifically?

Comment: No! JBoss also can present as a web server. You put kibana-3.1.0 under ROOT.WAR folder. Or if you use jboss 7 you put it under welcome-content.

Comment: Ok! And I guess in your answer you didn't put port number in the URL?? And the port number will be 80 not 9200 (which is for ES)? Right?

Comment: Yes. If you use apache, the default port is 80. But, if you use jboss, your url must add the port which point to your jboss server, for example, 8080. (http:/this.is.my.ip:8080/kibana-3.1.0/index.html)

Comment: And I ran Jboss server after putting kibana folder inside jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ROOT.war and then ran URL: http://this.is.my.ip:8443/kibana-3.1.0/index.html, but I get a blank white screen with black question mark on top-left. Any idea?

Comment: How about this link: this.is.my.ip:8443/kibana-3.1.0/index.html#/dashboard/file/default.json. Please make sure your kibana config have point to elasticsearch.

Comment: Same result! No change

Comment: elasticsearch: "http://localhost:9200" as presently I am trying this on my local machine

Comment: You can point like that. You have to point to  this.is.my.ip:9200

Comment: Now it works, but not exactly. I get Error Could not contact Elasticsearch at http://this.is.my.ip:9200. Please ensure that Elasticsearch is reachable from your system.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the latest installation and integration tutorial of Logstash, ElasticSearch and Kibana on Apache Logs.

[Installation Guide on Windows](http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/install-elasticsearch-kibana-logstash-on-windows.html)

[Log Analytics using ElasticSearch, Logstash and Kibana](http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/log-analytics-using-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana.html)